# Using an enum instead of a switch case in Gosu

Tags: enums, switch-statement, gosu, guidewire

I want to avoid creating a switch case and instead use an `enum` but when writing the following code, I get a compile error saying `unexpected token public`:

```
public enum Status {
  INACTIVE {
    public void doSomething() {
      //do something
    }
  },
  ACTIVE {
    public void doSomething() {
      //do something else
    }
  },
  UNKNOWN {
    public void doSomething() {
      //do something totally different
    }
  };

  public abstract void doSomething()
}
```

Basically what I want to achieve is something similar to this:

```
public enum Status {
   ACTIVE,
   INACTIVE,
   UNKNOWN;
}

switch (getState()) {
  case INACTIVE:
    //do something
    break;
  case ACTIVE:
    //do something else
    break;
  case UNKNOWN:
    //do something totally different
    break;
}
```

Is this allowed in Gosu? How should I go about achieving such a behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have miss-understood the concept of `Enum`. First of all, `enum` is inherited from `java.lang.Enum`. It's not allowed to implement inner classes to `Enum constants`. You have to consider ACTIVE,INACTIVE and UNKNOWN (`Enum constants`) as `objects` of `class type` Status. 
Proof:
`Status.ACTIVE.getClass()` == `class Status`
`Status.ACTIVE instanceof Status` == `true`
`Status.ACTIVE instanceof java.lang.Enum` == `true`
If you want to avoid the `switch` statement in your main code, you can move the `switch` into the implementation of `enum` as follows; (coded in Gosu)

```
enum Status {
  ACTIVE,INACTIVE,UNKNOWN;

  public function doSomething(){
    switch (this) {
      case INACTIVE:
         //do something
         break;
      case ACTIVE:
        //do something
        break;
      case UNKNOWN:
        //do something
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Now you have the capability to call the `doSomething()` method from the `enum constants` in your main code
Example:

```
var a=Status.ACTIVE
var b=Status.INACTIVE
var c=Status.UNKNOWN
a.doSomething()
b.doSomething()
c.doSomething()
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can read in
[Gosu grammar](https://gosu-lang.github.io/grammar.html) or below `function` is not allowed inside enum consts, even brackets `{}` after consts are not allowed.

What is allowed in enum body:

```
enumBody = "{" [enumConstants] classMembers "}" .
enumConstants = enumConstant {"," enumConstant} [","] [";"] .
enumConstant = {annotation} id optionalArguments .
```

So basically in GOSU enum contains consts and rest normally as in any other class.